# Why my getTimestamp() method doesn't work properly in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with a column type: timestamp.
The data stored there looks like this:

[image]

I want to make a simple select and find whether there's a date between a given begin date and end date.

This is what I do so far:

```
$starttime = $_POST['starttime'];
$duration = 15;//$_POST['duration'];

$converted_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-d-m H:i:s', $_POST['starttime']); // POST
$begin_timestamp = $converted_date->getTimestamp();

$quickReact = "SELECT start_time FROM commercial WHERE
 UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time) >= '$begin_timestamp' AND
 UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time) <('$begin_timestamp'+'$duration')";
```

What is worth mentioning, `starttime` is: `2015-10-30 16:14:44`.
Now, even though I've got results in my database that should fit into my query - I don't see them because somehow the UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time) brings incorrect value and parse the data incorectly.

This part in my php code doesn't work as it should:

```
$converted_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-d-m H:i:s', $_POST['starttime']); // POST
$begin_timestamp = $converted_date->getTimestamp();
```

because from `2015-10-30 16:14:44` given as a parameter, it returns the timestamp: 1497111284 which points to some date in 2017...
How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you aware that you can do this without converting to timestamp? Or is that a requirement for some other reason?

Comment: it is not! can you save me some time and help me with that?

Comment: look at what you are compareing

Comment: See answer below, let me know if anything doesn't make sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skip the conversion:

```
$starttime = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['starttime']);
$duration = 15;//$_POST['duration'];

$query = "SELECT start_time FROM commercial WHERE start_time >= '$starttime' AND start_time < '$begin_timestamp'+ INTERVAL $duration SECOND";
```

Of course, you should NEVER inject user-supplied data into an SQL query. This is just a proof of concept.

Comment: I added escaping to your code. Feel free to rollback. Having it in the code of the answer just helps drill it in better than just saying it IMO.

Comment: True, though I'd not recommend doing it that way either! Prepared queries are the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter.

Timestamps in MySQL are compared by giving string values to them, and MySQL has built-in functions to help.

```
SELECT start_time FORM commercial
WHERE start_time BETWEEN ? AND DATE_ADD(?, INTERVAL ? SECOND)
```

With those three parameters being `$begin_timestamp` twice and `$duration` for the third (Yes, use parameters!! They exist for a very good reason!)

I'm assuming your `15` is in seconds. If not, just change `SECOND` to whatever unit it is you want.